# Mpdf not downloading pdf from inline chrome browser (but displaying pdf)

Tags: javascript, php, mpdf

I used mpdf to display the pdf in my browser and it is working fine.

The pdf file is been shown in the browser but when the user clicks on the download button the php code is downloaded but not the pdf file displayed.

The below is my code

```
$mpdf=new mPDF( ); 
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;    
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
$filename='Test';

$mpdf->Output($filename.'.pdf', 'I');
```

I can't use D or F as shown below for mpdf as the user has to first view the pdf in his browser and then he has to download based on his interest.

```
$mpdf->Output($filename.'.pdf', 'D');
```

Any suggestions/ideas on how to download the pdf instead of code from the inline browser.

Comment: it wont download in Chrome.

Comment: @Bira, It works.... It worked for me in some of the pages

Comment: Show HTTP headers of the response. Most likely they are overriden (again) somewhere on the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
ob_clean();
$mpdf->Output($filename.'.pdf', 'I');
```

it should download now.

> Send the file inline to the browser. The plug-in is used if available.
>   The name given by $filename is used when one selects the “Save as”
>   option on the link generating the PDF

Comment: This here did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

This took me a lot, so I'm posting my answer here if anyone needs it.

```
// filename
$mpdf->Output($filename.'.pdf');

// You need to write this
$file = $filename.'.pdf';
$response = new \Zend\Http\Response\Stream();
$response->setStream(fopen($file, 'r'));
$response->setStatusCode(200);
$response->setStreamName(basename($file));
$headers = new \Zend\Http\Headers();
$headers = addHeaders(array(
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename"'.basename($file).'"',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Length' => filesize($file),
    'Expires' => '@0',
    'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate',
    'Pragma' => 'public'
));

$response->setHeaders($headers);
return $response;
```

Have fun coding! :)